# Subquery not returning all the results T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Subquery that is not returning the results I am looking for. I have 3 Locations that do not always have an Order Count for the date range in my condition and they are not returning with a result of 0. Instead I am losing all the other data for those parts. I'm sure there is a better way of querying the data, so here is my query.

```
SELECT b.Part, b.Location, b.Last_12_Mo, b.Last_6_Mo,
           COUNT(sd.SBINV) AS Order_Count
      FROM (
            SELECT a.Part, a.Location, a.Last_12_Mo,
                   ISNULL(SUM(sd.SBQSHP), 0) AS Last_6_Mo
              FROM (
                    SELECT t3.Part, sd.SBLOC AS Location, ISNULL(SUM(sd.SBQSHP),0) AS Last_12_Mo
                      FROM Top300 t3
                      LEFT JOIN SalesData sd 
                        ON t3.Part   = sd.SBITEM
                       AND sd.SBINDT > '20120315'
                     GROUP BY t3.Part, sd.SBLOC
                    ) AS a 
              LEFT JOIN SalesData sd
                ON a.Part       = sd.SBITEM
               AND sd.SBINDT    > '20121015'
             GROUP BY a.Part, a.Location, a.Last_12_Mo
            ) AS b 
      LEFT JOIN SalesData sd
        ON b.Part       = sd.SBITEM
       AND sd.SBINDT    > '20130110'
     GROUP BY b.Part, b.Location, b.Last_12_Mo, b.Last_6_Mo
     ORDER BY b.Part, b.Location
```

Comment: There is probably a way of formatting that query so we can all read it too... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT t3.Part, sd.SBLOC AS Location, 
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > '20120315' THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END),0) AS Last_12_Mo,
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > '20121015' THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END),0) AS Last_6_Mo,
COUNT(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > '20130110' THEN sd.SBINV END) AS Order_Count
FROM Top300 t3
LEFT JOIN SalesData sd  ON t3.Part   = sd.SBITEM
GROUP BY t3.Part, sd.SBLOC
ORDER BY t3.Part, sd.SBLOC
```

Based on OPs comments below, you need to join parts with location table to get combination of all parts and locations (Note: Change Location Column and Table Name to match your location table)

```
SELECT t3.Part,  t3.Location, 
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > '20120315' THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END),0) AS Last_12_Mo,
ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > '20121015' THEN sd.SBQSHP ELSE 0 END),0) AS Last_6_Mo,
COUNT(CASE WHEN sd.SBINDT > '20130110' THEN sd.SBINV END) AS Order_Count
FROM 
(SELECT DISTINCT a.Part, b.Location from Top300 a, LocationTable b)   t3
LEFT JOIN SalesData sd  ON t3.Part   = sd.SBITEM and t3.Location = sd.SBLOC
GROUP BY t3.Part, t3.Location
ORDER BY t3.Part, t3.Location
```

Comment: I am still not getting data for the Locations that have do not meet that criteria.

Comment: can you add sample data from both tables and expected result to your Question.

Comment: What I expect to see is a 0 in Sales for Part 456 in Location C

Comment: your data is not clear to understand, can you add that as table in your Question or create a [SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: In table t3, I have Part 123 and 456.  In table sd, I have Part 123, Locations A, B and C with Sales of 1, 2 and 3 respectively.  In table sd, I have Part 456, Locations A and B only with Sales 1 and 2 respectively.  Part 456 does not have any Sales data for Location C.  I want that to show as 0 Sales for Location C.

Comment: @user2174734, do you have any table that stores only location data.. you can return that from SalesData because you are joining parts to sales and if there is no part 456 in SD for C you cannot return that.

Comment: I do have a table that has location data only.  How would I bring that table into this query?

Answer (score 0):

Mate, inside the query you're using: sd.SBINDT > '20121015'

and outside, you are using:  AND sd.SBINDT    > '20130110'

results before the outside query wont return.